# Stream operations passing on duplicates

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I've this logic where I filter based on vendor id list `vendors`. Before iterating over this stream there are already 2 items in the collections with same vendor id as in the `vendors` list. However, once the list is process duplicates are not filtered and I get additional two items.

This is the code as below. What is wrong in the `filter` that negates the condition?

```
List<Vendor> nonConfiguredVendors = null;

if (entities.isEmpty()) {
    nonConfiguredVendors = vendors;
} else {
    nonConfiguredVendors = vendors.stream()
            .filter(vendor -> entities.stream()
                    .anyMatch(entity -> !vendor.getVendorId().equalsIgnoreCase(entity.getVendorId())))
            .peek(System.out::println)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Edit**: The `vendors` are having ids from `FC_101` to `FC_150`. The `entities` is already having `FC_133` and `FC_140` which are getting added again to the `nonConfiguredVendors` list

Comment: What part of this code do you expect to deduplicate?  The filter doesn't deduplicate, it just checks that the vendor IDs don't match anything in the entity stream.

Comment: Added an edit that elaborates further

Comment: Could you write a simple sample input and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not valid:

```
nonConfiguredVendors = vendors.stream()
            .filter(vendor -> entities.stream()
                    .anyMatch(entity -> !vendor.getVendorId().equalsIgnoreCase(entity.getVendorId())))
            )
```

In your case, you are accepting all vendors whose vendorId is found in entities: `anyMatch` will returns `true` if the `Predicate` returns `true` for any `T`.

Thus, leading to your issue.

The correct use case (but don't) would have been:

```
nonConfiguredVendors = vendors.stream()
            .filter(vendor -> entities.stream()
                    .noneMatch(entity -> !vendor.getVendorId().equalsIgnoreCase(entity.getVendorId())))
            )
```

[`noneMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) will return true if the `Predicate` never returns `true` or if the stream is empty.

You should pre-compute the vendorIds: computing it each time is not efficient.

```
var vendorIds = entities.stream()
                        .map(e -> e.getVendorId())
                        .collect(toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<String>());
```

Then filter:

```
var nonConfiguredVendors = vendors.stream()
                                  .filter(vendor -> !vendorIds.contains(vendor.getVendorId()))
            .peek(System.out::println)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a set of unique vendor ids in `entities` collection and then filter the vendors using this set

```
Set<String> uniqueIds = entities.stream()
                        .map(Entity::getVendorId)
                        .map(String::toLowerCase)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

nonConfiguredVendors = vendors.stream()
                .filter(vendor -> !uniqueIds.contains(vendor.getVendorId().toLowerCase()))
                .peek(System.out::println)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```